# Cannot add files to GitHub through Android Studio version control system (LF replace CRLF)

Tags: android, git, android-studio, core.autocrlf

I'm using Android Studio and I have around 3 files that cannot be added to my commits to GitHub because when I try (VCS > Git > +Add) I get this error:

> **Error Adding Files**
>
> The following problems have occurred when adding the files:
>
> fatal: **CRLF would be replaced by LF** in MyApp/app/src/.../blah.xml
>
> during executing git add --ignore-errors --
>
> MyApp/app/src/.../blah.xml

Why does this happen and what can I do on Mac to correct this problem **?**

I've tried entering into Terminal: `git config --global core.autocrlf false` and `git config --global core.safecrlf false` as recommended, but all this allowed me to do was add the files that were previously unaddable. Commiting the projects ran me into the same issue I was having before and I believe further complicated things (required creating a new changelist, which didn't even solve the problem). I've also looked into the Android Studio preferences, but there's nothing that allows me to configure line endings, especially between CRLF and LF preferences.

What I need a further explanation of: which line endings and formatting do CRLF and LF individually correspond to **?** And which applies to me, a Mac user on Android Studio working out of the program's built-in VCS **?**

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message?

Comment: I don't know what to do about the replacement, or what the replacement would even mean. Without full confidence in how to handle the issue, I also don't know how to proceed so I can be able to add my file to my git repo

Comment: As a start, do you know what CR and LF mean? If not, *find out!*

Comment: I understand it has something to do with line endings, but I can't find a straight-forward explanation of how it applies in my situation. That's why I came here so someone might explain the issue to me.

Comment: There are dozens of straight-forward explanations of this on SO already, why write another one?

Comment: tl;dr; It's Bill Gate's fault :). Windows implements line endings with 2 characters (\n and \r) while all other OSes use only \n, and that can cause problems (for example binary files and not matching line numbers shown in compiler outputs and IDEs). AFAIK you can change the preference in Android Studio to use \n ONLY, which wouldn't change anything for you, but make it easier for git to manage things and avoid a hell lot of warnings. EDIT: I don't have AS installed on my current machine, but check out [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-line-separators.html)

Comment: I tried exactly what I found online. The "dozens of straight-forward explanations" don't help much according to the limitations of Android Studio. If you have an answer, please post it so I can try it and give you feedback.

Comment: *"I tried exactly what I found online"* - so **what was that**, and what precisely was the outcome?! *"Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)"*

Comment: I understand your request. I've updated the question to further explain my lack of understanding and what I've tried.